# Change android home screen wallpaper using react native app

Tags: javascript, react-native, wallpaper, android-wallpaper

I want to Change android home screen wallpaper using react native app. Is there any other modules then rnwallpaper, react-native-wallpaper-manager or react-native-wallpaper-enhanced. None of these is working. Or any one using these packages by internally resolving issues of the these modules.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49740712/how-to-add-set-as-wallpaper-option-in-react-native-app  It seems someone did find how to get one of those modules to work