# Set phone background image using React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, background-image

I'm new to React, I managed to upload an image from the local phone gallery and store its URI in a global variable, but I can't find anywhere how to set the image to my **phone** background image (not in react!).
The end goal is to allow a change by date in the background.
Assuming I can use `global.frstImgURI`, and `global.secImgURI` and `global.thrdImgURI` as my images path (by import). How can I achieve that?

Currently, I manage to upload an image, then show it in my react native, BG, but not on my phone.
My current code for choosing image:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import global from '../components/global'

const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const BackgroundImg = () => {
    return <View>
                <ImageBackground
                    source={{uri: global.day1_image }}
                    resizeMode="stretch"
                    style={styles.img}>
                </ImageBackground>
            </View>
};
export default BackgroundImg;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    img: {
        height: screenHeight,
        width: screenWidth,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }
})
```

Show it on React BG:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import BackgroundImg from '../components/Background_image'
const App = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <BackgroundImg />
        </View>
    );
};
export default App;
```

My thought is using a dynamic list, and changing images by if statement connected to time (still didn't implement), but as said, I can't find how to change the phone image BG at all. Thanks!

Comment: By `phone background image` you mean actual phone wallpaper? On main screen where you have your apps/folders?

Comment: If so, then try [this](https://github.com/liuhong1happy/react-native-wallpaper-manager) or [this](https://github.com/meharbhutta/react-native-manage-wallpaper) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49740712/how-to-add-set-as-wallpaper-option-in-react-native-app). search `react native change phone wallpaper`

Comment: Hey, thank you for answering! Home screen, lock screen, or main menu on the phone. I might be mistaken, but the link you sent doesn't work for Expo, the first link, I am asking currently its programmer, the second saw as I said after some bug, and the third is ok I hope but somewhat complicated as it seems like there isn't any easy way to do it. Good to know what should I search for.

Answer (score 0):

In the case , import image with their extension , then direct pass ImageBackground

```
import global from '../assets/global.png'

const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const BackgroundImg = () => {
    return <View>
                <ImageBackground
                    source={global}
                    resizeMode="stretch"
                    style={styles.img}>
                </ImageBackground>
            </View>
};
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, but I don't need to pass global as I can get to its data via import and choose there what I need. If I understand your answer, it wasn't the main issue. My problem was "writing" the image to the Home screen, lock screen, or main menu on the phone.